# sox & alsa sound recording issue

Tags: audio, peripherals

I've installed sox and now this whole thing is freaking out :) I'm trying to get sox to record a flac file for me.

aplay and arecord work ok:

```
pi@raspberrypi /tmp $ arecord -d 3 test1.wav
Recording WAVE 'test1.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono

pi@raspberrypi /tmp $ aplay test1.wav
Playing WAVE 'test1.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
```

sox will convert the wav to flac with some warnings - I guess I can work out them later:

```
pi@raspberrypi /tmp $ sox test1.wav test1.flac channels 1 rate 16k
sox WARN rate: rate clipped 40 samples; decrease volume?
sox WARN dither: dither clipped 37 samples; decrease volume?
```

It sounds like a valid flac:

```
pi@raspberrypi /tmp $ mplayer test1.flac
Playing test1.flac.
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
libavcodec version 53.35.0 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.32.2
AUDIO: 16000 Hz, 1 ch, s16le, 38.1 kbit/14.89% (ratio: 4766->32000)
Selected audio codec: [ffflac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg FLAC audio)
==========================================================================
```

But when I'm trying to record anything with sox it will fail:

```
pi@raspberrypi /tmp $ rec -c 1 some.flac -t flac -r 16000 trim 0 0:05
rec WARN alsa: can't encode 0-bit Unknown or not applicable
Segmentation fault
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I found a [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.bugs.dist/jCqdwFWPUKk) explaining this a bit and was able to get rid of the first message by removing libsox-fmt-alsa. It hasn't helped recording though. I am going to build sox from its most recent sources to see if the fixes claimed have solved the issue.

Comment: Please write what external sound card are you using. From your post I can see that you are trying to record from a playback-only device.

Comment: Try adding `-t alsa` [at the end](https://github.com/floere/playa/issues/6#issuecomment-1414212093)

Answer (score 3):

Solution here:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=13088

> export AUDIODEV=hw:1,0
>
> export AUDIODRIVER=alsa

Of course you may have to adapt hardware id, guess it from `arecord -l`